# Copy-VMFile Hyper-V Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS from Windows Server 2019 Error

Tags: ubuntu, server, hyper-v

i try to copy file from host machine Windows Server 2019.
In host machine i run powershell as administrator and execute following command

```
Copy-VMFile "Test VM" -SourcePath "D:\Test.txt" -DestinationPath "/tmp/Test.txt" -CreateFullPath -FileSource Host
```

i got error "failed to initite copying file to guest. Unspecified error 0x80004005"

I have enabled all integration services for Vm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Cde.png)

Guest machine is hosted using Hyper-V and guest OS= Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS. From Microsoft docs LIS - linux integrations services should be enabled by default.

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

I also tryed to install them `apt-get install linux-virtual linux-tools-virtual linux-cloud-tools-virtual` but same issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so virtualization support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). I think you can ask on [sf] instead, but first I recommend taking [their tour](//serverfault.com//tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](//serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).